# VBA - Find number of times a value appears on another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm relatively new to VBA and I've ran into a problem.  I have a list of values in `Sheet 1` and all of those values are listed in `Sheet 2` as well.  Many of the values are listed multiple times in `Sheet 2`.  How do I count the number of times the value appears in `Sheet 2`, then add that number to `Cells(a,3)` in `Sheet 1` (where a corresponds to the row)?  I want to keep the listed values in Sheet 1 unchanged and only manipulate `Cell(a,3)` in each row.

I've tried numerous things but I really have no idea where to start.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try the countif worksheet function https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839272.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You would loop through your cells using something like:

```
For Each rngCell in Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))
    rngCell.Value = rngCell.Value + WorksheetFunction.CountIf('Sheet2!'A:AZ, "value")
Next rngCell
```

Where the for is looping through your first to your last cell in column 3, then adding the countif from sheet2 (change the A:AZ to whatever your used columns are) for "Value"

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without a loop by just assigning the `COUNTIF()` function to your range:

```
With Range("C2:C" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row)
    .Formula = "=COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A,A2)"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```